# Borrow a constant struct field together with mut self&

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm new to Rust and trying to understand how to properly handle the following borrow checker "problem":

I have a struct containing some fields, and I would like some of the fields to be constant over the lifetime of the object (const in C++). This way, I could borrow &mut self while also holding an immutable reference to the const field.

Here is a minimal example:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Process {
    const_data: HashMap<String, i32>, // this is supposed to never be changed after construction!
    mut_data: i32, // this is supposed to be mutated during object lifetime
}


impl Process {
    fn do_more(&mut self, num: &i32) {
        self.mut_data += num;
    }

    fn do_somethig(&mut self, name: &str) {
        let num = self.const_data.get(name).unwrap(); // reference to part of self.const_data
        self.do_more(num); // borrowing &mut self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut p = Process { const_data: HashMap::from([
        ("foo".to_string(), 1),
        ("bar".to_string(), 2),
        ("buzz".to_string(), 3),
    ]), mut_data: 0 };

    p.do_somethig("foo");
}
```

It fails to compile with the error message

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:16:9
   |
15 |         let num = self.const_data.get(name).unwrap();
   |                   ------------------------- immutable borrow occurs here
16 |         self.do_more(num);
   |         ^^^^^-------^^^^^
   |         |    |
   |         |    immutable borrow later used by call
   |         mutable borrow occurs here
```

Is there a way to mark `Process::const_data` as immutable, such that the borrow checker knows that its not contradicting the "one mutable reference" principle?

PS: In the example above we could make `Process::do_more()` take `num` by value and not by reference, however, in my actual project `const_data` would contain a complex struct which should not be copied or moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Rc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) to wrap your `const_data`. `Rc::clone` is a cheap operation.

```rust
use std::{collections::HashMap, rc::Rc};

struct Process {
    const_data: Rc<HashMap<String, i32>>, // this is supposed to never be changed after construction!
    mut_data: i32,                        // this is supposed to be mutated during object lifetime
}

impl Process {
    fn do_more(&mut self, num: &i32) {
        self.mut_data += num;
    }

    fn do_somethig(&mut self, name: &str) {
        let map = Rc::clone(&self.const_data);
        let num = map.get(name).unwrap(); // reference to part of self.const_data
        self.do_more(num); // borrowing &mut self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut p = Process {
        const_data: Rc::new(HashMap::from([
            ("foo".to_string(), 1),
            ("bar".to_string(), 2),
            ("buzz".to_string(), 3),
        ])),
        mut_data: 0,
    };

    p.do_somethig("foo");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that perfectly solves the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy your value. This should work:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Process {
    const_data: HashMap<String, i32>, 
    mut_data: i32, 
}


impl Process {
    fn do_more(&mut self, num: &i32) {
        self.mut_data += num;
    }

    fn do_somethig(&mut self, name: &str) {
        let ref num = self.const_data[name].clone(); // Reference to value similar to *self.const_data.index(name)
        self.do_more(num);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut p = Process { const_data: HashMap::from([
        ("foo".to_string(), 1),
        ("bar".to_string(), 2),
        ("buzz".to_string(), 3),
    ]), mut_data: 0 };
    p.do_somethig("foo");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunaly, this isn't an option, since the data in const_data is in reality a complex struct which definitely should not be copied just to make the program compile.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is because the borrow checker doesn't check if the `&mut Process` borrow actually modifies what part of the data. It just sees multiple borrows with one of them being mutable and that's not allowed.

The solution is to attach the `do_more` method directly to `mut_data`, like so:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MutData {
    data: i32
}
impl MutData {
    fn do_more(&mut self, num: &i32) {
        self.data += num;
    }
}

struct Process {
    const_data: HashMap<String, i32>, // this is supposed to never be changed after construction!
    mut_data: MutData, // this is supposed to be mutated during object lifetime
}


impl Process {
    fn do_more(&mut self, num: &i32) {
        self.mut_data.do_more(num);
    }

    fn do_somethig(&mut self, name: &str) {
        let num = self.const_data.get(name).unwrap(); // reference to part of self.const_data
        self.mut_data.do_more(num); // borrowing &mut self.mut_data
    }
}

fn main() {
    let const_data = HashMap::from([
        ("foo".to_string(), 1),
        ("bar".to_string(), 2),
        ("buzz".to_string(), 3),
    ]);
    let mut p = Process { const_data, mut_data: MutData { data: 0 } };
    
    println!("{:?}", p.mut_data);

    p.do_somethig("bar");
    
    println!("{:?}", p.mut_data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this wouldn't work for my actual project, since do_more() would eventually require the const data of the whole Process.

Comment: Or maybe `self.mut_data.do_more(&self.const_data)`?

Comment: Technically yes, but in practice this would require to propagate the const data through a whole series of function calls. The answer from zxch3n alrady points out a very good solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) to store the mutable portion of the struct, and then take a non-mutable reference to `self`:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Process {
    const_data: HashMap<String, i32>, // this is supposed to never be changed after construction!
    mut_data: RefCell<i32>, // this is supposed to be mutated during object lifetime
}


impl Process {
    fn do_more(&self, num: &i32) {
        *self.mut_data.borrow_mut() += num;
    }

    fn do_somethig(&self, name: &str) {
        let num = self.const_data.get(name).unwrap(); // reference to part of self.const_data
        self.do_more(num); // borrowing &mut self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p = Process { const_data: HashMap::from([
        ("foo".to_string(), 1),
        ("bar".to_string(), 2),
        ("buzz".to_string(), 3),
    ]), mut_data: RefCell::new (0) };

    p.do_somethig("foo");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=609c2c95e1fd420b617f8470432e4bf3)

PS: For an `i32` you would probably use [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) instead of `RefCell`, but I'm assuming that `mut_data` is really a more complex type where `RefCell` is justified.

Comment: Thanks, this would indeed work. However, in my case it would be very inconvenient to make do_more() operate on self& instead of &mut set, since there are actually a bunch of those functions.